# What versions of JDK7 are supported by Web Logic 11g

Tags: weblogic, java-7

I'm looking for the documentation of Oracle one matrix of compatibility between Web Logic and JDK 7 , but did not find the information of the operating systems that it 's compatibility or which versions of JDK7 , speaks only of 6 , could help ?

Link the doc : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/oracle-hyperion-epm-system-certific-131801.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Oracle Support website. It shows that all of the usual operating systems are supported for Oracle JDK 1.7.0_07 and higher for WebLogic 10.3.6.

https://support.oracle.com

Sign in, click on the Certification tab and search for product 'Oracle Weblogic Server'. Look for the JDK information under the Management and Development Tools section.